# Jmeter test run dont save at database table

Tags: testing, automated-tests, load-testing

I'm load testing an spring web flow aplication in jmeter and after run the tests, the informations dont get persisted on database. I am doing this path:

- Recording my test;
- Extracting the viewstate (its a spring web flow application);
- Running the same test (Theres any error in the result tree listener);

Obs: Its a user sign up funcionality.

So, anyone can help me with this?

Comment: What connection is your web flow application using during this test run? Is autocommit on?

Comment: I am using a JDBC connection and the autocommit is on.